# Is 'repeatable' a field type for meta boxes?

Tags: metabox

This  is probably a silly question, but I'm new to wordpress development so easily confused at the moment. Code:

`array(

        'label' => 'Repeatable',

        'desc'  => 'A description for the field.',

        'id'    => $prefix.'repeatable',

        'type'  => 'repeatable'

    )`

My Q: Is  `'repeatable'`  a standard feature of wordpress, or is it something the developer has created? (have picked this code off the internet to learn).

Thank-you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress has no real form API, you have to create almost all form elements from scratch.

`'type' => 'repeatable'` is part of an external library.

Google lead me to this article: [Reusable Custom Meta Boxes Part 3: Extra Fields](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reusable-custom-meta-boxes-part-3-extra-fields/) – maybe a starting point for your research?